# Filtering ASPxGridView by a ASPxDateEdit using Control

Tags: datetime, data-binding, filter, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to filter my gridview by choosing date and time in a dateedit. I put a button which has DataBind() controls. The query of the DataSource of the GridView has a WHERE clause. It has a Control connecting the gridview and the dateedit. When I test the query, it works fine. I enabled ButtonClick event and wrote the following code into that:

```
protected void ASPxButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateEdit.DataBind();
    SQLDataSource.DataBind();
    ASPxGridView.DataBind();
}
```

As you can see I bound all stuff that I need. But no items displayed when I choose date and time and click the button. Did I miss something? I appreciate if you help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the DevExpress ASP.NET Technical Evangelist, Mehul.

There are many ways you can approach this but I recommend using the ASPxGridLookup control which gives you a grid within a dropdown:
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/ASPxGridLookup/FilterServerMode.aspx

You can also use the built-in features:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q267406.aspx
Or try this sample:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2040.aspx

Some of these may help you as well:
http://search.devexpress.com/?q=filter+external&p=T4|P5|57

To answer your original question, this sample shows you how to databind on an external button click:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1662.aspx

Thanks, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not post the code showing how the SQLDataSource is adjusted.  However, I've tried to reproduce this problem and failed.  Here is my code:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvSupply" ClientInstanceName="gvSupply" Width="100%" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" KeyFieldName="OrderID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="OrderID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustomerID" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="EmployeeID" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="OrderDate" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([OrderDate] = ?)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxDateEdit1" Name="OrderDate" PropertyName="Value"
                    Type="DateTime" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 


        <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="ASPxDateEdit1" runat="server">
        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

I've tested the grid with the Orders table from the Northwind database.  Also, to test your query, I suggest that you handle the [Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx) event of the SQLDataSource and check the e.Command and e.Argumets parameters.  I hope, this information will be helpful to you.